# Writing Testcase in Rspec for Update method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am writing a Rspec for update method of a controller which updates the record in a table `T` with a given id `ID`. Here in spec I want to add a case that checks whether any record with `ID` exists in the table `T`, and if it does not exist, it should give error like following But being new to RSpec I could not complete it.

```
  it "should give error when record with the given id does not exist" do
    pending "case yet to be handled"
  end
```

So if anyone helps me in writing this spec.

Answer (score 0):

You could do `Model.find` and check if this record doesn't exist.

```
it "should give error when record with the given id does not exist" do
    expect { Model.find(<your ID>) }.should raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound::Error)
end
```

Comment: I would like to know if there is any way to know whether this given id is a valid id because always it may not be the last id of the model so I think it is better to check if the list of ids of the model includes the given id, but I don't know how to do that. If I am wrong, please rectify.

Comment: Actually I am using DataMapper instead of Active Record. So could you please tell me what change I have to do?

Comment: Try to fetch a non existing record using DataMapper or whatever you are using and look at what error it gives and replace ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound::Error with that particular error.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the parameter id  and use the correct HTTP verb to send request to update action. i.e

```
it "should give error when record with the given id does not exist" do
    put :update, id: <invalid_id>
    # you expectations here    
end
```

[How I learned to test my Rails applications, Part 4: Controller spe](http://everydayrails.com/2012/04/07/testing-series-rspec-controllers.html) has some example and more explanation on controller tests.

Comment: See I have written the same. But it is giving the following error:  "undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: In your controller, you are calling save on non existent object. You can check if the object exists and then only update the values and call save methods on it. I prefer to use updated_attributes method so that I don't have to call save method on it and later check if its successful or not.